# .NET Visual Studio using reference from NuGet causes Could not load file or assembly

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, nuget

I am having a reference (library) dependency problem by using NuGet which is annoying me, please find my projects and their relationship as below:

- `Utils` project depends on the `Newtonsoft.Json`
- `Project A` depends on the `Utils` project which is target for .NET runtime 2.0
- `Project B` depends on the `Utils` project which is target for .NET runtime 4.0
- `Project C` depends on the `Utils` project which is target for .NET runtime 4.5

I decided the `Utils` project should use the minimal required version of the `Newtonsoft.Json` which is `6.0.4` for `.NET 2.0` and I thought the consumers could override it automatically but I was wrong.

`Project A`, `Project B` & `Project C` will use a different version of `Newtonsoft.Json` for different .NET runtime. Now whenever the program stepped into codes inside `Utils` to use any reference of `Newtonsoft.Json` it threw an exception `Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies.`

Does anyone have a clue what should the keywords in Google or even better a solution? Thanks for your time and attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally solved the problem after hours have spent.

The trick is adding the following block to the `app.config`/`web.config` which makes the program to redirect the reference from the old version library to the new version. (Where the value `10.0.0.0` should be the version number of the newer library)

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"
            culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: thanks for sharing your solution here, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues.

Comment: @Leo I would like to but the SO policy need a few more hours to allow that :)